# Predict value using non numeric values in Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, linear-regression

I have a dataset with numeric and non-numeric .there are a column named as model name, manufacture year, transmission type, fuel type, Engine capacity and fuel consumption. I need to calculate fuel consumption with the above-mentioned factors.
I need to know how,
is possible to convert non-numeric values convert a numeric value and predict fuel consumption?

[Click here to visit dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEWW4.png)

Comment: [Pandas get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), [sklearn one-hot encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) and [labelencoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) can all be helpful in transforming categorical data into numeric

Comment: @G.Anderson Thank you very much I will go through the above libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transpose all the string values to columns and fill them with 0 or 1, sounds like a daunting task but like G. Anderson mentioned above there are libraries to make it super easy.

I would create a generic function using get_dummies something like this :

```
def dummy_df(df, todummy_list):
    for x in todummy_list:
            dummies = pd.get_dummies(df[x], prefix=x, dummy_na=False)
            df = df.drop(x, 1)
            df = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)
    return df
```

And Invoke the function with all the features that need to be dummy'fied

```
todummy_list = ['MODEL_NAME', 'TRANS_TYPE', 'FUEL_TYPE']
train = dummy_df(train, todummy_list)
```

## considering 'train' is a pandas dataframe.